# No encuentro append en JTextfield

Tags: java, mouselistener

Estoy programando una interfaz gráfica con un botón y a este botón le quiero asignar una accion con `MouseListener` para que cuando lo presione muestre un "1" en la caja de texto `JTextField` pero quiero usar **append** para esto y no me sale en NetBeans alguien sabe la razon de esto?:/ en todos los videos que veo les funciona normal pero cuando lo intento buscar en las sugerencias no me aparece a mi seria de gran ayuda me puedan decir la razón

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La razón, es que JTextField no tiene el método ``append``, este método pertenece al componente ``JTextArea``, para concatenar texto en un JTextField se debe usar algo como esto ``field.setText(field.getText() + " newtext")``

Comment: Bienvenido, siempre agrega el código como texto no como imagen ya que no es visible para todos los usuarios. Te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos.